# Excel 2016: Conditional Text + sense for missing values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a number in cell A1 that can is between 0 and 1000, and I want to assign it a text that indicates success of failture (here: Yes and No).

```
=IF(A1>200,"YES","NO")
```

This works well for all numbers. So far, so good. Now, however, I want to create a complete spreadsheet with 100s of cells where this formula is active. These have 100s of numbered cells that are not yet set (as measurement is collected over time).

I do not want a 'No' in there. I rather have no text. How do I do that? In a way I want to only have this formula working, when there is no NA, that means, not set value. A zero is not enough as zero (0) is a number.

I think something like this:

```
=IF(A1=NA,"", IF(A1>200,"YES","NO"))
```

Is there something that compares?

Comment: When you say `NA` is this the `#N/A` error or is it text `NA` in the cell?  If error then: `=IF(ISERROR(A1),"", IF(A1>200,"YES","NO"))` if text `=IF(A1="NA","", IF(A1>200,"YES","NO"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can check `A1` for `#NA` using `IF(ISNA(A1), "",...)`
- You can check it for any error using `IF(ISERROR(A1), "",...)`
- You can check it for blank using `IF(ISBLANK(A1), "",...)`
- However, you only want it to be a number, so your best choice here is `ISNUMBER`:

.

```
           =IF(ISNUMBER(A1), IF(A1>200,"YES","NO"), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

very close already ... I'd do

```
=IF(A1="","", IF(A1>200,"YES","NO"))
```

if column A originally is blank

and to take it even further ...

```
=IF(A1="";""; IF(TYPE(A1)<>1;"NaN";IF(A1>200;"YES";"NO")))
```

provides an additional check that in A1 there is a numeric value.